# Java -version giving me a "no such file or directory"

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu (just a disclaimer), but I tried setting my `.bashrc` path variable to

`export PATH=/my_path/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin:${PATH}`

as well as

`export PATH=/my_path/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:${PATH}`

and when I try `java -version` it says there's no such file or directory. Am I not setting it right. It seems like my path should be fine...

`wveteam@wveteam-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /home/jaayers/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/
total 19760
drwxr-xr-x 2 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:11 bin
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143     3339 Jul 25 12:07 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x 4 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:07 db
drwxr-xr-x 3 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:07 include
drwxr-xr-x 5 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:08 jre
drwxr-xr-x 5 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:14 lib
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143       40 Jul 25 12:07 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 4 uucp 143     4096 Jul 25 12:07 man
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143      114 Jul 25 12:07 README.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143      498 Jul 25 12:07 release
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143 19902768 Jul 25 12:07 src.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143   110114 Jul 25 01:21 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143   173559 Jul 25 12:07 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt`

Comment: Did you source your .bashrc after modifying it? Can you post the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: sanity check  /my_path/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -version

Comment: possibly a problem with dynamic linking. what do you get when issuing `ldd /my_path/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java`?

Comment: @HeinerWestphal I get a `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: @sreya Did you try running ``java`` providing the full path to the executable? Are the permissions OK on the ``java`` binary? Could you post the output of ``ls -l <path_to_java>``?

Comment: By the way, you should probably ask a question like this on http://askubuntu.com/, a place for all you Ubuntu woes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have installed the wrong architecture of java (32bit on top of a 64bit system or viceversa)

Comment: I don't think so, it's 64bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @sreya: He may be right.  If you do `file ..../bin/java`, does it say 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: as Heiner said, `file /my_path/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java`?

if you don't have multilib (32bit compatibility), even `file` won't understand exec format

Comment: ah! you're right, it says ELF 32-bit, so find the 64bit version then?

Comment: yes, it's the fastest solution, oracle ships different versions, don't know about ubuntu packages names

Comment: This was the issue for me. Thanks - only taken me 7 man hours...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try something like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/my_path/jdk1.7.0_67
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be exporting the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/my_path/jdk1.7.0_67
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Java is not installed correctly on your machine, that's why the machine can't find java.

You need to update altenatives in UBUNTU. Use the below command

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/path-to-jdk/bin/java" 1

and then run "java -version" you should be able to find java. :)